# Postfix/dovecot; How to avoid the <end> in the subheader of Outlook 2013?

Tags: outlook, raspberry-pi, postfix-mta, raspbian, dovecot

Recently, with the help of some tutorials, I successfully set-up my own mailserver on my Pi 2 using postfix and dovecot. Everything works well, however, when I receive e-mail in Outlook 2013 I always see "`<end>`" in the preview of the message below the header. **Is there a way to fix this in the configuration of postfix/dovecot?**

Please see screenshot below to give you and idea:

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you very much for your help!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Microsoft Outlook, that when the entire message is displayed in the preview pane, it adds `<end>` at the end, to tell you that what you see is all of what you get.

I don't know why you need to "fix" this, but as far as I know the only to to prevent the message preview from displaying `<end>` is to make the message long enough that the end of the message doesn't make it into the preview pane.